# label does not exist in current context in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <h4 class="text-center a_z_search">Registered Office</h4>
    <ul class="a_cmppro_add">
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAddres" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblURL" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In above code I used label controls when I build it giving errors label does not exist in current context in asp.net I analyse and removed designer also but doesn't solved this error please help me thank you in advance...

Comment: what the error you are getting

Comment: We cant help without more informations. It's like going to the car workshop and saying that there's an issue with your car without mentioning what

Comment: Wild guess, they are in a Repeater or DataList... Those are index based and you need FindControl to locate them (Google has plenty of examples)

Comment: "Removed designer"?

Comment: removing your designer file was probably not a good idea. If you're lucky, VS will generate you a new one. Anyway the lines generating the errors are probably in your code behind, not in the code shown here. So we're flying a bit blind.